# Drop duplicate rows, but only if column equals NaN

Tags: python, dataframe

I only want to drop rows where two columns (ID, Code) are duplicates, but the third column (Descrip) is equal to 'NaN'. My dataframe, df (Shown below) relfects my intial dataframe and df2 is what I want instead.

```
df:

ID    Descrip    Code
1     NaN        CC
1     3          SS
2     4          CC
2     7          SS
3     NaN        CC
3     1          CC
3     NaN        SS
4     20         CC
4     22         SS
5     15         CC
5     10         SS
6     100        CC
6     NaN        CC
6     4          SS
6     NaN        SS


df2:

ID    Descrip    Code
1     NaN        CC
1     3          SS
2     4          CC
2     7          SS
3     1          CC
3     NaN        SS
4     20         CC
4     22         SS
5     15         CC
5     10         SS
6     100        CC
6     4          SS
```

I know using df.drop(subset['ID', 'Code'], keep='first'), would remove the duplicate rows, but I only want this where 'Decrip' == 'NaN'.

Comment: What do you mean by ID and Code columns matching?

Comment: Just edited, I meant duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and take the max value (every number is larger than NaN):

```
df2 = df.groupby(["ID", "Code"])["Descrip"].max().reset_index()
```

Comment: Could you descripe why the above works in a few steps. I'm trying to learn more about Python and it's functions. + from me btw, cool answer and it yields the desired results though swapping the last two columns.

Comment: Sure - first the `groupby` creates groups of rows with the same value in both columns `ID` and `Code`. Then we select the max value of the `Descrip` column for every group. Since we used `groupby`, the returned value will have the `ID` and `Code` columns as index, so we do `reset_index` to make them columns.

You can read about this type of functions here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use:

```
df = df[~(df.duplicated(['ID','Code'], False) & df['Descrip'].isna())]
```

Where (and I'll try my best to explain as to my understanding):

- `df.duplicated(['ID','Code'], False)` - Returns a boolean if there is any duplicate in the subset `ID` and `Code`, where `False` ensures all rows are considered. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).
- `df['Descrip'].isna()` - Checks wheather or not `Descrip` holds `NaN`. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)
- `df[~(....first point above .... & .... second point above ....)]` - The tilde stands for `not` operator to invert the boolean mask and the ampersand chains these two expressions together with bitwise `and`, together filtering out the rows of interest. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

***Result:***

```
    ID  Descrip Code
0    1      NaN   CC
1    1        3   SS
2    2        4   CC
3    2        7   SS
5    3        1   CC
6    3      NaN   SS
7    4       20   CC
8    4       22   SS
9    5       15   CC
10   5       10   SS
11   6      100   CC
13   6        4   SS
```